# git fetch changes from a local branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have a `git` problem with a local branch and I don't know how to solve it. After reading some topics on stack overflow I thought I found the solution but `git` produces an error I don't understand.

I have a `master` branch which is a few commits behind my `development` branch. Since I want to make a bugfix on the `master`, I made a `feature branch` and I want to get these changes into my `development` branch. So I thought I switch to my `development` branch and I could just `fetch` this new `featurebranch` but I am getting the message that the `featurebranch` is no repository...

```
$ git fetch clusters
fatal: 'clusters' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
$ git branch
  clusters
* develop
  master
  plotlydev
  protrna_plot
  release010
```

So how do I get the changes within my `featurebranch` into my `development` branch?

Answer (score 2):

`fetch` retrieves changes from a remote. You're thinking of `merge`

```
git checkout develop
git merge feature
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know that `fetch` is solely for remote repositories! Thanks. But since my `develop` branch has already new features etc, If I *just* merge my feature, it tries to remove a lot of new code. Is there a way to just incorporate the changes between `master` and `featurebranch` into my `develop` branch?

Comment: It won't remove any code unless you specifically committed deletions on your feature branch. And according to your question, feature should contain all changes that master has already, but if not, then you can merge it in the same way. `git checkout develop` and then `git merge master`

Comment: You  can use git cherry-pick to pull in a specific commit from your master branch into your develop branch.